# Split list in python

Tags: python

I have following list:

```
mylist = ['Hello,\r', 'Whats going on.\r', 'some text']
```

When I write "mylist" to a file called file.txt

```
open('file.txt', 'w').writelines(mylist)
```

I get for every line a little bit text because of the \r:

```
Hello,
Whats going on.
some text
```

How can I manipulate mylist to substitute the `\r` with a space? In the end I need this in `file.txt`:

```
Hello, Whats going on. sometext
```

It must be a list.

Thanks!

Comment: what does this have to do with "splitting a list" (your title)? I am trying to see but I do not see yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mylist = [s.replace("\r", " ") for s in mylist]
```

This loops through your list, and does a string replace on each element in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
open('file.txt', 'w').writelines(map(lambda x: x.replace('\r',' '),mylist))
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list to a match with a regular expression to replace /r with a space.

Comment: A regular expression would be overkill for a simple replace.

Comment: Was a downvote really necessary? My answer wasn't wrong. There are better answers and I'll admit that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have this luxury, but I actually like to keep my lists of strings without newlines at the end. That way, I can manipulate them, doing things like dumping them out in debug mode, without having to do an "rstrip()" on them.

For example, if your strings were saved like:

```
mylist = ['Hello,', 'Whats going on.', 'some text']
```

Then you could display them like this:

```
print "\n".join(mylist)
```

or

```
print " ".join(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.rstrip()`:

```
>>> mylist = ['Hello,\r', 'Whats going on.\r', 'some text']
>>> ' '.join(map(str.rstrip,mylist))
'Hello, Whats going on. some text'
>>>
```